# Angular detect input when data is the same

Tags: angular

Hello I have this input from firebase which is displayed, and I user .dirty() and .valid() function. All I want when I change the value the input will be disabled.

here's the snippet.

```
    if(this.tripStatusForm.valid && this.tripStatusForm.touched) {
      this.appSpinner = false
      this.isDisabled = true
      // this.dbService.getServiceUpdate(
      //   this.StatusForm.controls,
      //   new Date(), this.dateChange).then((resp: any) => {
      //   }).finally(() => this.activeModal.close())
    } else {
      this.showAlert("danger", "No Changes made!")
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: You have described the scenario and added some code, but there is no question. Please add a desired behaviour, and a clear problem or error statement. Also the title doesn't match the content.

Comment: You wanna a deep check if are all values the same as on init?